# Unable to set custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I just installed Oneiric Oncelot. It's on a Lenovo 4446-25U laptop, running Unity, nothing really customized yet, it was a fresh install. I wanted to add a keyboard shortcut for Terminator and Netbeans and few other apps I use. For instance, I want Terminator to run when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, Firefox when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, etc.

I opened the System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > + ... added "Launch Terminator" with a command of "terminator" and clicked "Apply." It shows up in the list with "Disabled" to the right. So I click on it to highlight it and press my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key combo ... and it stays at Disabled. So I look around in the shortcuts, and I'm able to set the key combo for the other items. For instance, for "Launch Terminal" I highlight it, press "Enter" and it says "New command..." and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it works.

I thought, oops, doubled a command. So I disabled the "Launch Terminal" shortcut with backspace, went back to my custom one, and it still doesn't read the key combo. It still just says "Disabled."

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2):

`click on that disabled text` then it will ask for new acceleration keys now hold the keys that you wanna set.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](http://www.thebitbangtheory.com/2011/10/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-xdotool/).

Ocelot uses Unity with Compiz and the shortcuts you are editing are for Gnome. If you install the CompizConfig Settings Manager, launch it, under General check off Commands to enable it and then add your custom shortcuts there.